# Polylang - Post to use both languages

Tags: woocommerce, translation, polylang

I have Polylang Pro, bought it thinking that i can set 2 languages in one post. Unfortunately i cant.

I have several woocommerce products/categories, and they do not require translation. I want the products to show on both the languages. But i can see them in only one and for the other i have to translate. I do not want to do this.

Is there any way that we can set the woocommerce products/categories to show on both languages?

What i did so far is that i used the `if((get_bloginfo("language") == 'en-GB')||((get_bloginfo("language") == 'in-TA'))`to check manually in some pages but it doesn't really solve the issue

Comment: Ask support on that. I know for sure WPML have option to show original content if no translation is made.

Comment: @MartinMirchev hello. i tried but they dont know as well. Funny. So i made a script that automates duplicates this for the second language.